# DataGridView for a list of classes without accessors

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a list of objects (`List<MyClass>`) whose members I would like to have visible in a DataGridView on a selective basis.

Here is my class:

```
class MyClass
{
   public int X;
   public int Y;
   public int Z;
}
```

Is it possible to have just the `X` and `Y` members visible in the grid without the use of accessors? I tried adding columns to the DataGridView but the data wasn't being filled (but I could have been doing this wrong. I just created a column with the same name as the field).

I am binding the list to the control with the following code:

```
datagrid.DataSource = list;
```

Any help on this would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your class; you are having public members but not public properties. Bindable controls such as DataGridView bind with public properties with `get; set;`

In short you need to change your class

```
class MyClass
{
    public int X
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Z
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And then in designer specify column's `DataPropertyName` to respectively

```
DataPropertyName = X
DataPropertyName = Y
DataPropertyName = Z
```

Comment: What if the DataPropertyName value would be dynamic, i.e. determined at runtime? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141494/does-datagridview-always-depend-on-public-properties-for-column-values.