# Does DataGridView always depend on public properties for column values?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

At runtime, I have a collection of rows (`Row` class). Each of them consist of column values, represented by instances of a `ColumnValue` class. The name of the columns are determined at runtime, and are in a separate columns descriptor collection (`Column` class).

I want to create a `DataGridView` that displays all `Row` instances. Of course, the `DataGridView`'s columns shall be exactly those specified by the `Column` instances in the containing collection.

But since `DataGridView`'s columns can fetch their values from a list item's public properties only, **and I *cannot easily* define such a property at runtime**, I cannot use `DataGridView` to display the tabular data.

**Correct**?

Consider these VB classes for example:

```
' Classes for table structure representation
Public Class TColumn ' describes my columns
  Public Name As String
  Public Index As Integer

  Public Sub New(ByVal AName As String)
    Name = AName
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class TTable ' describes a table
  Public Name As String
  Public Columns As Collection

  Public Sub New(ByVal AName As String)
    Name = AName
    Columns = New Collection
  End Sub
End Class

' Classes for table data 

Public Class TRow ' Container for one row's column values
  Public ColumnValues As Collection
  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    ColumnValues = New Collection()
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class TTableData ' Container for a table's rows
  Public Table As TTable
  Public Rows As Collection
  Public Sub New(ByVal ATable As TTable)
    MyBase.New()
    Table = ATable
    Rows = New Collection()
  End Sub
End Class
```

And this main form code:

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim T As TTable
    Dim TD As TTableData
    Dim CV As Collection
    T = New TTable("Sample")
    T.Columns.Add(New TColumn("Column1"))
    T.Columns.Add(New TColumn("Column2"))

    TD = New TTableData(T)
    CV = New Collection
    CV.Add("Row1Col1")
    CV.Add("Row1Col2")
    TD.Rows.Add(CV)

    CV = New Collection
    CV.Add("Row2Col1")
    CV.Add("Row2Col2")
    TD.Rows.Add(CV)

    ' Question: How can I create a DataGridView that displays this:
    ' 
    '     Column1   Column2
    '     Row1Col1  Row1Col2
    '     Row2Col1  Row2Col1
    ' 
    ' WHILE the Columns collection contents are dynamic, i.e. determined at runtime, not at compile- or design-time?
  End Sub
End Class
```

I wonder what `DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName` value I would specify for example when defining (at runtime) `Column1`'s `DataGridView` column???

**Generally asking: Is it true that `DataGridView` always wants to fetch the data from object instances with public properties, and those define the column structure and especially values? I cannot display stuff that does not have public properties at all?**

Comment: can you add an example please?

Comment: Hope the sample shows that I do not have a chance to at runtime or design-time specify the property that delivers a specifc column's data...

Comment: I'm not sure if I would upvote that question of mine. Thus thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView` and set `e.Value` to `table(e.RowIndex)(e.ColumnIndex)`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Wasted six hours with experimenting, to no avail. Will check this asap, thx.

Comment: Where would i set the e.value value?

Comment: Inside the CellFormatting handler, e is parameter of handler of type DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs

Comment: Saw that, wondered where/when i'd write my col/row info into it. Will probably become clear when i am back at my desk.

Comment: OK, that works for the display process. What if I want to make the DataGridView data-bound? I think instead of working around the property-getting-and-setting automatism, I should consider using virtual mode. There I have full control over the data i/o without being "bound" to public/published properties. I'll accept your answer anyways.

Comment: Okay, virtual mode is definetely the way to go if you cannot bind to property-based values. I just went this path, and it gives you total freedom regarding the way you access the data shown in the DataGridView.